# XO - Promotions are not getting index in elasticsearch

Tags: smarttarget, experience-optimization, deployer-extension, elasticsearch, sites-9.5

When the smarttarget component is published, the item is not getting pushed to elastic search index (xo-contentfragments), the log shows the XoContentFragmentDeploy step is executed, but the cd_xo log showing only one below log entry when published

> 2021-01-14 13:22:54,368 INFO
> [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12]
> XoConfigurationReader - Loading smarttarget_conf.xml configuration.

In cd_core logs, I can see that the step is processed.

> 2021-01-14 12:42:05,749 DEBUG
> [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
> PipelineActor - Step 'XoContentFragmentDeploy' of pipelineId:
> 'Tridion-Process-PostCommit' for 'tcm:0-435249-66560' processed.
> 2021-01-14 12:42:05,764 DEBUG
> [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
> HybridStateStore - Found pipeline entity for execution id:
> tcm:0-435249-66560 and pipeline id: Tridion-Process-PostCommit

Comment: I did a test at least in the 9.5 + DXA 2.2 + XO module it was working fine. maybe you are still missing some configuration. Are you migrating from the Fredhopper to Elastic? or trying to set up from the scratch? Ensure your regions are created correctly? and indexes are created correctly?

Comment: I migrated from fredhopper, I am able to create new promotions from Targetting and those data are getting pushed to elasticsearch where as the new published promotions items are not getting indexed on elastic search. No error shown thee deployer showing xo item got processed, but no luck

Comment: Promotions from Targeting are being added via the Xo-Management service, whilst actual CPs are being added via the Deployer. The fact that XO Promotions are being updated doesn't mean that your published content also reaches ES. In your case, the issue is most probably with the Deployer.

Comment: Thank @AtilaSos, going through the configs if I can find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was silly mistake during the deployer config. The XO deployer pipelins configs should have been placed  after the **Tridion-Commit-TX** pipe line, instead I have placed the same at the end. Thanks Brian from SDL support for noticing the same.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Can you accept your answer to keep unanswered questions minimum? Thank you!

Comment: done, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A couple of failure points that you can look at for your implementation would be your [start up parameters](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/741832/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/upgrading-the-------------experience-optimization-------------content-deployer-extension) for your deployer to include es-host and es-port highlighted below.

```
Elasticsearch:
--es.host=10.100.101.52 (Elasticsearch server)
--es.port=9200 (port number of the Elasticsearch)
```

A quick verification would be to also check if the add-on is deployed correctly with the correct JSON parameters as per the [online documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/813722/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/setting-up-your-upgraded-content-deployer-for-your-setup/procedure) specifically the environment variable in the add-on should match the environment name defined in your deployer start up / environment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Shiva, Gone through these, I have followed the xo upgrade document, https://docs.sdl.com/816112/741832/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/upgrading-the-------------experience-optimization-------------content-deployer-extension . I don't think I need content mashup or content expression, as I am doing this via deployer., I can also see below log, not sure if that helps..

2021-01-17 11:02:03,733 DEBUG [http-nio2-8084-exec-5] HybridStateStore - Removing step ID: ExecutionId: tcm:0-435273-66560, PipelineId: Tridion-Process-PostCommit, StepId: XoContentFragmentDeploy elapsed 0